# 'Move' a component into a portal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-portal

I have a component which renders an image, when the user clicks on it I want it to render through a portal without having to reload the image which is what's currently happening, this is a simple example:

```
export const TestPortals = (props: any) => {
    const element = <img src="imageurl.com/image.jpg" width={100} height={100} />
    const [inPortal, setInPortal] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
    return inPortal ? ReactDOM.createPortal(element, document.getElementById("portal")) : element
}
```

When the state switches to inportal = true the image itself reloads itself.

I'd like it to switch to rendering from the portal without that happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, "portal" means to render React component outside of the root.
That means that when ever you changing the state to render a portal, React **appends** new Dom element to the body.

This means that the image got rendered by the browser second time, this is how browsers work, you can do anything in React to change this behaviour.

Comment: Facebook does it somehow where a playing video will go over to the side and continue playing. I'm not necessarily saying portals are the solution, I'm really just asking for how I can achieve the same result.

Comment: Facebook uses pip (picture in picture) browser feature